# Using NodeJS and RavenDB in the cloud (appharbor)

Tags: node.js, cloud, ravendb, appharbor, cloud-hosting

I have written an application in nodejs/ravendb using node-ravendb (https://github.com/mattdaly/node-ravendb).

Now I want to find good hosting for it and i realize that I don't have much to choose from.

The only cloud-based hosting service that i have found that works with both RavenDB and NodeJS is Appharbor.

But when i try to use it with node-ravendb I find that node-ravendb only uses username/password for authentication and Appharbor wants to use APIKEY instead.

Can I make node-ravendb use APIKEY or is there another way?

Is Appharbor really my only alternative? I am also wondering if using RavenDB with nodejs is a good idea since it does not seem like a common configuration. Can anyone comment on that?

Comment: Can you raise an issue [here](https://github.com/mattdaly/node-ravendb/issues) please?  The node client is Matt Daly's thing, and hasn't been updated in awhile.

Comment: Also, there are some folks on the [RavenDB Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/) that have successfully used RavenDB on Windows Azure - which I belive also supports node.js.

Comment: Voting to close only because this isn't a good question for StackOverflow's format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported out of the box AFAICT. You'd need to modify node-ravendb to use API key.

Another option, since you mentioned cloud providers: why not just [run a virtual machine in Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/), and install and run anything you want? Then you don't have to futz with node-ravendb source code or API keys.